# Updating JavaFX BarChart data causes memory leak

Tags: java, javafx-8

I've discovered what I believe is a memory leak in JavaFX (1.8u40 GA and 1.8u60 b10 EA) [BarChart](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/BarChart.html) triggered by replacing all the data values in the series. This is exasperated by our application which does this several times a second.

Using `jvisualvm` shows an uncontrolled growth in the number of javafx.scene.layout.StackPane instances which eventually results in an OutOfMemoryError. Styled StackPane nodes are used internally by BarChart for the bars.

I've tried a different strategies to update the list. All exhibit the same issue.

```
// 1
series.getData().clear();
series.getData().addAll(list);
// 2
series.getData().setAll(list);
// 3
series.setData(list)
```

Interestingly the example in the [Oracle BarChart tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/bar-chart.htm#CIHJFHDE) updates values by adding all the bars/points first, and then mutating them using [XYChart.Data.setYValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Data.html#setYValue-Y-). This could work, but is not convenient for us as the number of data points can vary dynamically.

Specific questions

- Is there anyway to avoid this issue, other than a extra logic using the setYValue() approach above.
- Have I stumbled across an actual memory leak in JavaFX? or just an artefact of my misuse of the API? Surely freeing internal nodes when data is updated is JavaFX responsibility

Example

```
public class ChartUpdate extends Application {
    private int clock;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 100, 10);
        yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        BarChart<String, Number> graph = new BarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        graph.setAnimated(false);
        Series<String, Number> series = new Series<>();
        graph.getData().add(series);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(graph));
        stage.show();

        Timeline timeLine = new Timeline();
        timeLine.getKeyFrames().add(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500),
                        (e) -> {
                            ObservableList<Data<String, Number>> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                                list.add(new Data<>(String.valueOf(i), (clock + i) % 100));
                            }
                            series.setData(list);
                            clock++;
                        }));
        timeLine.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeLine.play();
    }
}
```

- Update (16th April 2015) Raised https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8094805 and posted to OpenJFX mailing list

Comment: I think that this bug in fixed in 8u60. But it's a beta version.

Comment: I've had a look in JavaFX JIRA, but I couldn't find the JIRA, do you know the reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary this was a genuine issue accepted by JavaFX team and fixed by JDK-8094805 in 8u60

See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8094805 for more detail.